# Can Chartjs create grouped charts programmatically?

Tags: chart.js

My web application gathers response times of multiple servers of a system and displays the response times of in a chart using charts Version 4

```
var data = {
  labels: ["PR1","EC1"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "pr1app1",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      barThickness: 20,
      data: [3,0],
    },
    {
      label: "pr1app2",
      backgroundColor: "red",
      barThickness: 20,
      data: [4,0],
    },
    {
      label: "pr1app3",
      backgroundColor: "green",
      barThickness: 20,
      data: [7,0],
    },
    {
      label: "ec1app1",
      backgroundColor: "yellow",
      barThickness: 20,
      data: [0,15],
    },
  ],
};
```

The labels 'PR1' and 'EC1' are systems. Each of these systems may have multiple application servers and each application server has a response time. This data is retrieved from an API.

I want the chart to be displayed like this:
[The current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdCwT.png)

In summary, I want the application servers of a given system grouped together. I can do this by setting the corresponding indexes of each of the systems to 0. For e.g, PR1 has 3 servers. Therefore, I have the values 3,4 and 7 in the 0'th index of the data arrays and at index 1, i've set the value to 0, so that EC1's server values are not displayed.

Similarly, I set the 0'th index of EC1's data array to 0, such that PR1 server values are not displayed but I can still see the colours of PR1's servers, although, they're barely visible.

I would like to know if this is the only way to display the chart in the way I want or if there are any other options. I'm open to other chart libraries if I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative configuration, that might be more appropriate for your data, is to have a
separate y axis for each system (`"PR1"` and `"EC1"` in the example). This way, each axis/system will only contain data for its servers; then those axes will be stacked (see [this docs example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/stacked.html)) creating the appearance of a single axis.

A starting configuration based on that idea and the OP example data could be:

```js
const data = {
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "pr1app1",
            backgroundColor: "blue",
            barPercentage: 1,
            categoryPercentage: 0.9,
            //barThickness: 20,
            data: [3],
            yAxisID: 'y2'
        },
        {
            label: "pr1app2",
            backgroundColor: "red",
            barPercentage: 1,
            categoryPercentage: 0.9,
            //barThickness: 20,
            data: [4],
            yAxisID: 'y2'
        },
        {
            label: "pr1app3",
            backgroundColor: "green",
            barPercentage: 1,
            categoryPercentage: 0.9,
            //barThickness: 20,
            data: [7],
            yAxisID: 'y2'
        },
        {
            label: "ec1app1",
            backgroundColor: "yellow",
            barPercentage: 0.3,
            //barThickness: 20,
            data: [15],
            yAxisID: 'y'
        },
    ],
};

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        indexAxis: 'y',
        scales: {
            y: {
                stack: 'systems',
                type: 'category',
                labels: ["EC1"]
            },
            y2: {
                type: 'category',
                stack: 'systems',
                labels: ["PR1"]
            }
            
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
            }
        }
    },
};

new Chart('chart1', config);
```

```html
<div style="height: 240px">
    <canvas id="chart1">
    </canvas>
 </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.0/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-6HrPqAvK+lZElIZ4mZ64fyxIBTsaX5zAFZg2V/2WT+iKPrFzTzvx6QAsLW2OaLwobhMYBog/+bvmIEEGXi0p1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```